# PDO login if statements

Tags: php, pdo

I'm trying to check if my users inserted in the correct information and it's giving me an UNDEFINED PDO error.

I want to be sure if a user fills in an incorrect password/username they get the error I've set, but its now coming out that way.

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username"><br />
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password"><br />
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])){
        require'core/connect.php';

        $query = dbConnect()->prepare("SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username = :username AND password = :password");
        $query->execute(array(
            ':username' => $_POST['username'],
            ':password' => $_POST['password']
            ));

        // check to see if username & password is correct
        if(!$query->prepare($_POST['username'])){
            echo 'username is incorrect.';
        }
        if(!$query->prepare($_POST['password'])){
            echo 'password is incorrect.';
        } else{
            if($query){
            header("Location: index.php");
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: What would you expect to get from `$query->prepare`? There's no `prepare` method in [`PDOStatement`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php).

Answer (score 2):

Your logic is incorrect. What you should do instead:

- Step 1: fetch user by username
- Step 2: check the password

If either step fails, reject the login. Ideally with the same message, to avoid leaking usernames.

The PDO error itself is because you're calling `prepare()` in a case where it shouldn't get called. To prepare a statement means to send an actual SQL statement to the server so as to get an pre-planned executable SQL statement. (By sending the username or password all by itself, you're basically sending invalid SQL.)

Lastly, you shouldn't store passwords in clear text like that. Use PHP's password functionalities in PHP 5.5, or `bcrypt()` (`crypt()` with `CRYPT_BLOWFISH`) if you're using older versions of PHP:

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.password.php
- http://php.net/crypt

Answer (score 0):

try this. You don't need check separately username or password

```
$query = dbConnect()->prepare("SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username = :username AND password = :password");
$query->execute(array(
    'username' => $_POST['username'],
    'password' => $_POST['password']
    ));

if ($query->rowCount() == 0) {
    echo 'Username or password is incorrect'
} else {
    header("Location: index.php");
}
```

Comment: `rowCount()` may not work with `SELECT` see [**Manual**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php)